# Cannot build XCode project from command line but can from XCode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, xcodebuild

I've created in XCode a simple navigation-based iPhone app. The app builds and runs properly from under XCode but I cannot get it to build from command line.

From terminal I execute:

```
xcodebuild -project George.xcodeproj -alltargets -parallelizeTargets -configuration Debug build
```

but I get that error:

```
=== BUILD NATIVE TARGET George OF PROJECT George WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===
Check dependencies
[BEROR]Code Sign error: The identity 'iPhone Developer' doesn't match any valid certificate/private key pair in the default keychain

** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    Check dependencies
(1 failure)
```

Is there something wrong with the way I try to handle it?

Comment: Are you getting same error in Xcode if you build for iOSDevice?

Comment: Are you getting same error in Xcode if you build for configuration Debug?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In addition to unlocking the keychain, you might also specify the codesign identity (or set it in your target). Development certs take the form 'iPhone Developer: Company Inc', distribution certs like this 'iPhone Distribution: Company Inc'.

```
xcodebuild -project George.xcodeproj -alltargets -parallelizeTargets -configuration Debug build CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY='iPhone Developer: Company Inc'
```

Comment: This worked for me, however I also deleted any expired certs which were still hanging around in the keychain.

Answer (score 6):

You can build from the command-line a build targeted at the simulator without signing issues.

This solved the signing issue for me:

```
xcodebuild -sdk iphonesimulator
```

Source: 
[xcodebuild Code Sign error: No matching codesigning identity found:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25050506/xcodebuild-code-sign-error-no-matching-codesigning-identity-found)

That's particularly useful if the command line build is there only to sanity check the source code in a continuous integration setup.

Answer (score 4):

Most probably your keychain is locked. Try unlocking it before executing the script, you can do it from command line (right before building):

`security unlock -p YourPasswordToKeychain ~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain`

Note, I'm using "login" keychain which could be different in your case

Also, if that doesn't help, try removing all other parameters and just leave smth like this:

`xcodebuild -configuration Debug` and clean beforehand `xcodebuild -configuration Debug clean`

Comment: For good measure I also did: Keychain / <keychain name, eg login> / <my certificate> /  Get info / Trust / When Code signing, always trust.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using shenzhen, it shows this error too.

Turns out, it happens when I plug in my iPad but it is not in the provision profile. By passing `--verbose` to shenzhen. it shows:

```
Check dependencies
Code Sign error: No matching provisioning profiles found: None of the valid     provisioning profiles include the devices:
XXXX’s iPad
CodeSign error: code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 8.3'
```

unplug the device, everything works just fine...

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the purpose of your script, it may also be sufficient to just turn off code signing in the script, which you can do by setting CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY=''

```
xcodebuild -project George.xcodeproj -alltargets -parallelizeTargets -configuration Debug build CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY=''
```

Obviously that's no good if you are trying to do a final build from a script, but it may be fine if you're just trying to do a test build for continuous integration (eg from Jenkins, to make sure that nobody has broken anything).

Answer (score 1):

I had an archiving error similar but not quite the same as the original post:

```
** ARCHIVE FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    Check dependencies
(1 failure)
```

This turned out to be a missing Application Service (in my case, the HealthKit service/entitlement), which I had enabled in my development App ID but not my production App ID.

You enable services in the Apple Member Center: https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/identifiers/bundle/bundleList.action

Answer (score 0):

This can be fixed in XCode 8.0 by changing from "iOS Distribution" to "iOS Development" in XCode. It doesn't seem like it should work, but it does for some reason.