# Building from the command line with xcodebuild results in code sign error

Tags: ios, xcode, vim, xcodebuild, clang-complete

I can build from xcode just fine, but not from the command line using xcodebuild. I'm trying to set up vim and some plugins like clang_complete. I need the output from the command line build to put in a .clang_complete file, etc.

Here is my error

```
$ xcodebuild -project Proto.xcodeproj -alltargets

=== BUILD NATIVE TARGET Proto OF PROJECT Proto WITH THE DEFAULT CONFIGURATION (Release) ===
Check dependencies
Code Sign error: The identity 'iPhone Developer' doesn't match any valid, non-expired certificate/private key pair in your keychains


** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    Check dependencies
(1 failure)
```

I have tried the suggestions in this [so question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7635143/cannot-build-xcode-project-from-command-line-but-can-from-xcode). The suggestions also failed.

```
$ xcodebuild -configuration CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY='iPhone Developer: Company Inc'                                                                     
--- xcodebuild: WARNING: Configuration CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY=iPhone Developer: Company Inc is not in the project. Building default configuration.

=== BUILD NATIVE TARGET Proto OF PROJECT Proto WITH THE DEFAULT CONFIGURATION (Release) ===
Check dependencies
Code Sign error: The identity 'iPhone Developer' doesn't match any valid, non-expired certificate/private key pair in your keychains


** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    Check dependencies
(1 failure)
```

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I might correct this. I do not have a developer license to install my app on a device, just registered as a member. Does this make a difference? Seems like it wouldn't since I can build from xcode.

Also as a secondary last resort type question is there anyway to extract the compiler commands to put in a .clang_complete file even if I can't build from the command line? The reason to do this is explained in this [objective vimmer post](http://objvimmer.com/blog/2012/08/17/objective-c-code-completion-in-vim/)

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Did you ask the author of that blog?