# xcodebuild Code Sign error: No matching codesigning identity found:

Tags: ios, xcode, profile, xcodebuild, codesign

I am currently in process of developing my app and haven't enrolled into App developer program.
Though have mac, created apple id and developing my app with simulator.
Question:

1. Do you need to enroll (pay $99) to use xcodebuild (the commandline tool to build)?
2. I have created a starter app and was able to build successfully with XCode (IDE) but while building the same with  xcodebuild -target   -sdk iphoneos -configuration debug
   I was getting

   ```
   Code Sign error: No matching codesigning identity found: No codesigning identities (i.e. certificate and private key pairs) matching “XXXXXX” were found.
   CodeSign error: code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 7.1'*
   ```

And then  I changed "Code signing identity" and updated with "Don't code sign"

Now I am only getting

```
CodeSign error: code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 7.1'*
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to build for the device you need pay $99 to enroll in the iOS developer program. Without doing that you can only compile for the simulator

Comment: at this time my goal is to just build for simulator, is there any param i need to pass to xcodebuild to specify that I am building for simulator?

Comment: Try changing `-sdk iphoneos` to `-sdk iphonesimulator`

Answer (score 0):

So the two issues are that you are telling it to build for device with -sdk iphoneOS there should be a different parameter you can pass for that flag which will represent the simulator.

You can also help guide it by adding the -destination flag and telling it you want to build with the intention of the simulator.

This information can be found on the [xcodebuild manual page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/xcodebuild.1.html)